# Eclipse WebView

Tags: eclipse, webview

I would like to open url´s in webview instead of in a webbrowser. I´m no programmer and can´t find a solution. Help would be greatly apreciated. I would like the url to open in a new activity called: activity_webview. Thanks in advance

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import com.casovi.luxury_new.R;

public class MainCars extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cars);
    }

    public void GoKoenigsegg(View view) {
        goToUrl("http://www.koenigsegg.com/");
    }
    public void GoMercedes(View view) {
        goToUrl("http://www.mercedes-amg.com/#/home");
    }

    private void goToUrl(String url) {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your main activity like this:
first create a webview,
second enable webviewclients,
third enable contentview,
finally load your desired url.
All the best..

```js
public class MainCars extends Activity {

WebView web;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    web = new WebView(this);  
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.koenigsegg.com/");
    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    setContentView(web);
}
```